# Is there some global object in PHP (like the window object in JavaScript)?

Tags: php

Is there some global object in PHP where all the methods, variables, objects, functions... (all PHP thinds) are laying? Such object in JavaScript is called the window.

I want to understand what exactly the PHP programming is. For example, the JavaScript programming (as I understand) is a manipulation with leafes-objects of the BOM tree - "you are taking one leaf-object of the BOM, then you are doing something with this leaf-object and you are saving the result in another leaf-object of the BOM"

I want to understand the structure of data that I am dealing with. For example, if I am writing $x=10; - the variable is created. where is it laying? It has to be connected to some object.

Comment: No, it does not

Comment: There doesn't have to be a window object in JavaScript.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It's within whatever *scope* it's in. When you write `$x = 10`, you can access that variable via `$x`. There's no alternative implicit `window[$x]`. There doesn't have to be.

Comment: That's the same as in Javascript BTW. `function () { var x = 10; }` – `x` isn't connected to any object here.

Comment: Your ` $x` variable is only accessible from the current scope which is the executed function. In fact in php nothing is accessible outside of its scope excepted GLOBAL and php SUPER_GLOBAL (without explicit include)

Comment: I think the most useful thing for you is to throw any expectations you already have out the window and plainly take PHP's manual at face value. Variables have scopes. There's one global scope, everything else is a function scope, and every new `function` introduces a new scope. Period. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to give you a little tour on scope in PHP.

It's exactly the same thing as every programmatic languages. You can have access to a var only in its execution scope.

Case 1 :

```
function bar() {
    $x = 10; // $x can be used in bar function only
}
```

Case 2 :

```
class foo() {
    private $x;

    //$x can be used in every foo class methods by using $this->$x

}
```

Case 3 :

```
class Foo() {
    public $x;
    //$x  $foo = new Foo(); $foo->x;
    // **everywhere = everywhere you are including the file which defines Foo class
    public static $y;
    //$y can be used everywhere by using : Foo::y
}
```

And to finish, you can define globals. Accessible from everywhere :

```
define("X", "something");
```

Hope it gives you a better idea of what is php variable.

PS : window object in javascript is not an object "where all the methods, variables, objects, functions..." are defined. It's just an object managing some things of the browser tab.

Comment: *"As in every language… only in execution scope…"* *cough cough* [dynamic scoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Lexical_scope_vs._dynamic_scope) *cough cough* – `private` and `public` doesn't actually have much to do with scoping, but with *visibility*, which is a separate concept. – `define()` doesn't define "globals", it defines **constants**, which is yet something different.

Comment: Also, `public $x` cannot be accessed by `Foo::x`.

Comment: agree with you, sorry, i didn't have too much time to explain what is vars.. for your information constants defined like this are also globals : http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php But yes it is constant.